# python: can't open file 'app.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: dockerfile

I've tried to run my docker image which has run a python file called ./app.py.This command is not working correctly why???

Docker File

[image]

folder structure
[image]

Comment: You seem to have attached two images to your question in place of the source code necessary to reproduce the issue.  (I can't, for example, run `docker build` that PNG file.)  Can you delete these images and replace them with your actual Dockerfile and the actual error message you're getting, as text and not an image?

Answer (score 0):

do you have your main folder 'flask-app' into your PYTHONPATH ?